# Why Prolog can't see the obvious answer?

Tags: function, math, prolog

```
f(9) = f(A), X = A, X = T * T
```

Why prolog cant see A = 9, X = 9, T = 3/-3, am I making a syntax error here? If so what is the correct form of this query? I am getting false, but there is obviously an easy answer to this equation.

Comment: Yes `T = 3/-3` is a syntax error, it should rather read `T = 3/ -3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in one sense you are making an interesting error because you are magically expecting prolog to be able to deduce a solution from a constraint (X=T*T)  (NOTE: that's a good thing, that's a very prolog expectation).  there are two things not working here

- to get prolog to understand you want to evaluate a math expression you need to use "is" instead of equal
- you need to give prolog a hint about what values might work for T

here is something in the neighborhood of what you were trying that will work

```
f(9) = f(A), X = A, between(-100,100,T), X is T * T
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the good solution already proposed by @madeofmistake, another alternative is to use the library for [constraint logic programming over finite domains](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/clp/clpfd.pl) (clpfd). After loading this library, you can use the operator `#=` to evaluate arithmetic constraints.

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- f(9) = f(A), X = A, X #= T * T.
A = X, X = 9,
T in -3 \/ 3.
```

Comment: yeah, i didn't know if it was worth jumping this far ahead, but this is the best way to do it